# How to number two equations as one

Tags: equations, align

```
\begin{align}
E\left(y_{i}^{T}|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_{1},u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_{2}\right)&=\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}\left[\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\\
&\qquad + \left. \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right]
\end{align}
```

The code above gives two equation numbers but I want only one since they belong to only one equation. How do I do that?

Comment: `equation` with `split` inside helps here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it to your own document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}% edit it to meet your preference
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E\left(y_{i}^{T}|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_{1},u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_{2}\right)
&=\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}\left[\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\\
&\qquad + \left. \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Suggestion

To make the code more readable (to make you easier to locate what you want to modify), remove the unnecessary `{}` (such as replacing `X_{a}^{b}` with `X_a^b`) and align the equation code with a better pattern as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it to your own document class
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}% edit it to meet your preference
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E\left(y_i^T|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_1,u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_2\right)
&=
\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_1,\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_2}{\sigma},\rho\right)}
\left[
    \phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_2}{\sigma}\right)
    \Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_1-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_2}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^2\right)^{1/2}}\right)
\right.\\
&
\qquad +
\left.
    \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_1)\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_2}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_1}{\left(1-\rho^2\right)^{1/2}}\right)
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `article` for the example code, without irrelevant tokens that can be disorienting.

Comment: @egreg: I have considered this negative effect many times so I started giving some comments to warn users that some additional tokens should not be used for their own purposes. I think I need to have a package derived from `standalone` class that does my common settings out of the box via key-value options, e.g., `\documentclass[<key-values>]{derivedstandalone}`. My settings are used to generate the tight output to mimic the screenshot output.

Answer (score 4):

### Option 2

Use `multline` instead of `align` (option 1 already in DonutE.Knot's answer...)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
E\left(y_{i}^{T}|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_{1},u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_{2}\right)=\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}\left[\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\\
\qquad + \left. \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

As Barbara Beeton states in her comment, the equation doesn't fit in the page, so it would be better to add another break, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
E\left(y_{i}^{T}|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_{1},u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_{2}\right)\\
=\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}\left[\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\\
+ \left. \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the position of the equation number says that something is wrong here; the problem is that the equation is wider than the page allows.  breaking it into three parts can still be done with `multline`.  (i still think that using `[final]` mode as default is a latex mis-feature.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know. Added a possible alternative. Feel free to edit my answer if you think there is a better alternative.

Comment: except that i'd prefer to see the equals sign at the beginning of the second line, that's just fine.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Corrected. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: I'd rather not recommend `multiline` especially when there is more than one line break, then proper use of `align` is a lot better. Especially when margins are changed.

Comment: @daleif So in this case it would be `split`, but this is already in the other answer...

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple use of `\nonumber` after the part of the equation which should not have a number (before the `\\`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    E\left(y_{i}^{T}|u_{1i}\succ-x_{1i}'\beta_{1},u_{2i}\succ-x_{2i}'\beta_{2}\right)&=\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}\left[\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-\rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\nonumber\\
    &\qquad + \left. \rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]