# Error in multline

Tags: equations, multline

This is related to my early [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147906/how-to-number-two-equations-as-one#147908), but with some changes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{multline}
 E(y_{i})=
\left(
 x_{2i}'\beta_{2}+
\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho\right)}
\left[
\phi\left(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-   \rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)\right.\\
\qquad 
+ \left. 
\rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}\right)
\right]
\right)
\times\Psi\left(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho
\right)
\end{multline} 
\end{document}
```

I have no idea why this is generating an error. `!Missing right \.inserted`

Comment: Please always post complete documents showing all required packages, not just fragments

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: I am sorry. I do have that in the original code. I missed here.

Comment: You are missing a `\right.` just before ``\\`` and a `\left.` just after it, but in this case they don't work well because of the ``\\`` itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really had to use `\left` and `\right`... Additional ones marked.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{multline}
 E(y_{i})=
\left(
 x_{2i}'\beta_{2}+
\frac{\sigma}{\Psi\left(
x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho
\right)}
\left[
\phi\left(
\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}
\right)\Phi\left(
\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-   \rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}
\right)
\right.
\right. % PS
\\
\qquad 
+ \left. 
\left. %PS
\rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi\left(
\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)^{1/2}}
\right)
\right]
\right)
\times\Psi\left(
x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho
\right)
\end{multline} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You'd got one left/right pair mis-matched but using `\left( zzz\right.` is not optimal anyway as the matching brackets will not be given the same size as the open is sized on the expression before `\\` and the close is sized on the expression after `\\`. Using fixed size delimiters makes it easier to avoid the error and produces matching delimiters:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multline}
 E(y_{i})=
\Bigl(
\bigl(
 x_{2i}'\beta_{2}+
\frac{\sigma}{\Psi (x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho)}
\bigl[
\phi(\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma})\Phi (\tfrac{x_{1i}'\beta_{1}-   \rho\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}}{(1-\rho^{2})^{1/2}})\\
\qquad 
+  
\rho\phi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1})\Phi(\tfrac{\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma}-\rho x_{1i}'\beta_{1}}{(1-\rho^{2})^{1/2}})
\bigr]
\bigr)
\times\Psi(x_{1i}'\beta_{1},\tfrac{x_{2i}'\beta_{2}}{\sigma},\rho)
\Bigr)
\end{multline} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really good looking...

Comment: @karlkoeller yes well once the error is fixed and the OP can see the expression, then work can be put into adjusting the setting, but that's a different question/

Comment: Anyway the first and the last parenthesis are not needed.

Comment: @karlkoeller well it's better to have them both than just one (which was the source of the original error:-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, know that you can avoid `\left[ \right]` by using `\Big[ \Big]` or `\Bigg[ \Bigg]` to manually get the desired size of brackets.